# How is the comparison b/w pointers & integers

Tags: c

I want to print all the addresses are the same if the particular addresses in a two dimensional arrays are the same. Looking at error:

```
comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
```

One thing I have understood is I can't compare addresses. It would give me a compilation error. But isn't there any method of doing that. How should my program check that all address are same and then it should print out the statement.

```
/* Address and  pointers*/ 

#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int a[10][20]; 

  a[1][1]=3;

  printf("%p %p %p %p", a[1], a+1, &a[1] , &a[1][0]); 

  if( a[1]== a+1== &a[1] == &a[1][0])
     printf("\nAll are same address\n"); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `%p` with something that's not `void *` causes undefined behaviour. Often we can gloss over that point, but it's actually relevant here, so that line should be:

```
printf("%p %p %p %p", (void *)a[1], (void *)(a+1), (void *)&a[1] , (void *)&a[1][0]);
```

Moving onto `a[1]== a+1== &a[1] == &a[1][0]`. I'm sure you recall that `==` is a binary operator (i.e. takes exactly two arguments), which evaluates to either `0` or `1`, and is left-associative. So this expression is:

```
((a[1] == a+1)== &a[1]) == &a[1][0]
```

Now, `a[1] == a+1` is `1` since those are alternative syntax for the same thing. So now we move onto evaluating `1 == &a[1]`.  Since `1` is an `int` and `&a[1]` is a pointer, this comparison is ill-formed.

In general, if your intent is to check that four items are all equal you need to write `if ( A == B && A == C && A == D )` or equivalent.

However, `if ( a[1] == &a[1] )` is also a constraint violation. To compare two pointers, it only works if they are both the same type (implicit conversions may be done here). However there is no implicit conversion from `int *` to `int (*)[3]` or vice versa.  To attempt this comparison you must cast at least one of the operands. One option is to cast both to `void *` as this is always legal and it must point to the first byte of whatever the operand was pointing to:

```
if ( (void *)a[1] == (void *)&a[1] )
```

So to summarize, your code could better be written as:

```
void *p = a[1];
void *q = a + 1;
void *r = &a[1];
void *s = &a[1][0];

printf("%p %p %p %p\n", p, q, r, s);

if ( p == q && p == r && p == s )
    printf("All are same address\n");
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb sir can you explain this line "However there is no implicit conversion from int * to int (*)[3] or vice versa" with an example & edit you answer a little bit?

Comment: @StackOverflow look up *implicit conversion*, it's too big a topic to cover in my post... basically, some types have implicit conversion and some dont (e.g. `int` to `double` does, but `int` to `int *` doesn't)